# Splitting a row based on a column value

Tags: sql

I have the following table output- 
What I have:

```
Account No     Description    Seg1    Seg2    Seg3      Budget     PeriodBalance
000-1120-00    Cash            000    1120     00       $1,000.00    $2,000.00
000-1130-00    Asset           000    1130     00       $1,500.00    $3,000.00
```

What I would like to have:

```
Account No    Description   Seg1    Seg2    Seg3    Budget      PeriodBalance
000-1120-01   Cash           000    1120    01      $700.00      $1,300.00 
000-1120-02   Cash           000    1120    02      $900.00      $1,700.00
000-1130-00   Asset          000    1130    00    $1,500.00      $3,000.00
```

Here, if the Seg2 is equal to 1120 then I would like to split it into 2 accounts suffixing the account No with 01 and 02 in place of 00 in segment 3. Once I have that, I would like to obtain the budget and the periodbalance for the new accounts. My original query is the following (Dynamics GP database Fabrikam):

```
Select 
rtrim(c.Actnumbr_1) +'-'+ rtrim(c.Actnumbr_2)+ '-'+ rtrim(c.Actnumbr_3) as ACTNUMST, 
    c.ACTINDX,
    c.ACTDESCR, 
    c.ACTNUMBR_1, 
    c.ACTNUMBR_2, 
    c.ACTNUMBR_3,  
    sum(a.PERDBLNC) as Period_Balance,
    b.BUDGETAMT, 
    a.year1, 
    '' as docdate,
    ''as Vendname,'' as PONUMBER,  
    0 as PO_Amount,     
    0 as 'Not_Received_Amount', 
    0 as ENCMBAMT 
from GL00100 c
left outer join GL11110 a on c.ACTINDX = a.ACTINDX
Left outer join 
    (Select 
        actindx, 
        sum(budgetamt) as budgetamt 
    from GL00201  
            where BUDGETID = 'budget2017'
                and periodid <= 12 group by actindx) b 
    on c.ACTINDX = b.ACTINDX
    where 
    a.PERIODID <= 12 and 
    a.year1 = '2017' and a.actindx < '18'
    group by 
    c.ACTDESCR, c.ACTNUMBR_1, c.ACTNUMBR_2, c.ACTNUMBR_3, a.year1,c.ACTINDX,b.BUDGETAMT
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What sql? Microsoft? MySQL?. Then what version?

Comment: What is the logic to get those numbers? The data make no sense

Comment: As described above the logic is simple - to split 1120 (seg2) in two rows replacing the 3rd segment with 01 (for the 1st split) and 02 for the second split. Because they will become a different account (string), their description, budget and period balance will change which are stored in diff tables. Currently I am just looking for the split (forget about the budgets and period balance). How can I just split the 1120 segment into 2 so that I have 2 accounts.

Comment: Simple if your maths is bad. Where do 700, 900, 1300, and 1700 come from in the 2nd result? Compared to 1000, 2000 in the first result? **They do not add up**. Going past the bad maths, why 700/900 and not 200/1400 or 600/800?

Comment: Hi Gbn, let's consider we split the budget and the period balance in 50-50.  and it is 500 and 1000 for both the accounts. Though practically, each account could have different budget and period balance.

Comment: Account No    Description   Seg1    Seg2    Seg3    Budget      PeriodBalance
000-1120-01   Cash           000    1120    01      $500.00      $1,000.00 
000-1120-02   Cash           000    1120    02      $500.00      $1,000.00
000-1130-00   Asset          000    1130    00    $1,500.00      $3,000.00